# Origin of "Inverse Pythagorean Theorem"

Tags: mathematics, geometry, trigonometry

There is a lot of information on the history of the Pythagorean theorem, but not much on its closely related cousin; the [Inverse Pythagorean Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Pythagorean_theorem). Would appreciate any resources on the the history of this theorem, not exclusive to "The first time it was written" (although that would be cool).

Comment: It seems also to be named "Reciprocal Pythag,"  so maybe more info under that name?

Comment: It is a simple special case of the "Law of Cosines" which was first stated by Regiomontanus (Johann Muller). Perhaps this special case did not draw much attention when the Law of cosines was published.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be pretty commonplace as well as having multiple names.  Here's an [article](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Nelsen2009-316026.pdf) which references some other article, both relatively recent.

[image]